# Async await is not working inside loop for me using Cypress-promise

Tags: cypress

i get error Your callback function returned a promise which never resolved and my code and i am cypress 3.4.1 version

````
```cy.xpath(LOGO).then(async $ele => {
      for (const i in $ele) {
        if ($ele.eq(i).text() === 'USA') {
          $ele.eq(i).click();
          cy.wait(5000);
        }
        const count = await cy.get(COUNT).invoke('text').promisify();
        if(count>0) break;
      }`enter code here`
});```
````

Comment: You should note the plugins you're using, otherwise it's gonna look like you want to get support for plain Cypress, while you're really looking for [cypress-promise](https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-promise) support. Best ask in the repo directly (which I see you've already [done](https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-promise/issues/4)).